# the associate of a prime is prime in integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-factorization, integral-domain

I was hoping someone could give me a hand getting started trying to prove that in an integral domain, if a and b are associates, then a is prime if and only if b is.

Answer (score 3):

You can test an element being prime by looking at the principal ideal, it generates. If two elements are associates, they generate the same principal ideal. This is the whole proof.